# Java 8 date time types serialized as object with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an entity with fields of Java 8 date time types. The issue is that these fields are serialized as object. I added the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency, so Spring Boot 1.5.7 would auto configure the `JavaTimeModule` that handles Java 8 date time types. It seems that the module is not registered (I put a breakpoint in JavaTimeModule constructor). I know I don't need a custom `ObjectMapper`. I spent hours reading about that issue and the solution is always to add the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency but it does not work in my case.

The entity:

```
@Entity
public class DateTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDate localDate;

    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    private Instant instant;

    private OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime;

    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;

}
```

The RestController method:

```
@GetMapping("/datetimes/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<DateTimeEntity> getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    DateTimeEntity dateTimeEntity = dateTimeRepository.findOne(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<DateTimeEntity>(dateTimeEntity, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

The JSON object returned:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "localDate": null,
    "localDateTime": null,
    "instant": {
        "epochSecond": 1508772600,
        "nano": 0
    },
    "offsetDateTime": {
        "offset": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "Z",
            "rules": {
                "fixedOffset": true,
                "transitionRules": [],
                "transitions": []
            }
        },
        "dayOfMonth": 23,
        "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
        "dayOfYear": 296,
        "month": "OCTOBER",
        "monthValue": 10,
        "year": 2017,
        "hour": 15,
        "minute": 30,
        "nano": 0,
        "second": 0
    },
    "zonedDateTime": {
        "offset": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "Z",
            "rules": {
                "fixedOffset": true,
                "transitionRules": [],
                "transitions": []
            }
        },
        "zone": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "Z",
            "rules": {
                "fixedOffset": true,
                "transitionRules": [],
                "transitions": []
            }
        },
        "dayOfMonth": 23,
        "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
        "dayOfYear": 296,
        "month": "OCTOBER",
        "monthValue": 10,
        "year": 2017,
        "hour": 15,
        "minute": 30,
        "nano": 0,
        "second": 0,
        "chronology": {
            "id": "ISO",
            "calendarType": "iso8601"
        }
    }
}
```

The POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mockito.version>2.11.0</mockito.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>output-html</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This Jackson module is deprecated. Read the documentation: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310, and use the non-deprecated replacement.

Comment: I found an useful post [here](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2014/09/java-8-localdate-with-jackson-serialize.html) where the author uses `@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)` on  the parameters. 
in addition to it as mentioned by @JB Nizet use the newer maven dep

Comment: It's deprecated but do you know why Spring Boot Autoconfigure is still using it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5fb9162875840db11d6bd9879eb30673240b1222/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/pom.xml#L54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add the dependency to the classpath. For some reason, it was not in the IDE.

Even though the dependency is deprecated, it's still used by `spring-boot-autoconfigure` module. See [Spring Boot Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5fb9162875840db11d6bd9879eb30673240b1222/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/pom.xml#L54)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

when it's in the classpath, Java 8 date and time objects are serialized as a timestamp.

Comment: It is actually surprising how this is an accepted answer, since this dependency is in question author's `pom.xml` file. It didn't work and for a good reason - adding the dependency wouldn't be enough. You need to wire the module in. Disscussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874510/spring-boot-2-5-0-and-invaliddefinitionexception-java-8-date-time-type-java-ti/76591039#76591039

Answer (score 38):

I started having this issue in the upgrade of spring boot from 2.3.7 to 2.5.1.

If you have an ObjectMapper @Bean defined, then you'll want to register the time module with it.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper defaultMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); 
    return objectMapper;
}
```

A lot of the time, coders will just create a "new ObjectMapper()" when using jackson serialization so keep an eye out for using the vanilla mapper, rather than autowiring a pre-configured default that has the time module registered.

As mentioned, you'll need the jackson-datatype-jsr310, but this is included in spring boot as a managed version.

If you don't define an object mapper bean manually, then spring boot should automatically provide one with the time module registered.

Comment: i solved this by adding @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class) before the localdatetime field. I think it is a bug in the latest versions of jsr310

Answer (score 8):

You can also try to use

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        .build();
```

JavaTimeModule is from package com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310 I have used library jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar

Comment: You are well come Umair Aslam :)

Answer (score 7):

According to  [How to customize ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) :

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module will be
>   automatically registered with the auto-configured
>   Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and applied to any ObjectMapper instances
>   that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for contributing
>   custom modules when you add new features to your application.

Just adding the dependancy is not enough, you have to declare a `@Bean` of you module like follow:

```
@Bean
public Module dateTimeModule(){
    return new JavaTimeModule();
}
```

Plus `jackson-datatype-jsr310` module is deprecated you should use [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) instead.

Comment: You don't need to declare a bean since spring boot auto configure is automatically registering it if it's found in the classpath which was my issue. The jar was not in the IDE classpath

Comment: Wrell thanks for sharing, i had a similar issue and i resolved it by declaring Beans, it could also have been due to the classpath. Nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are currently using String Boot 2.5.4 + Apache CXF (Java config) for JAX-RS, the below config solved problem for me

```
dependencies{
    constraints{
            implementation("org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs:3.4.4")
            implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.12.5")
            implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:2.12.5")
    }
}
```

```
dependencies{
    implementation("org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8")
}
```

Spring Boot (*org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder*), automatically registers the following well-known modules if they are detected on the classpath:

- jackson-datatype-jdk8 : support for other Java 8 types like java.util.Optional
- jackson-datatype-jsr310 : support for Java 8 Date & Time API types
- jackson-datatype-joda : support for Joda-Time types
- jackson-module-kotlin : support for Kotlin classes and data classes
  are auto-configured in case the needed class are on classpath

But to use CXF it seems we need to initialize it with correct serialization provider. And in case we not pass Spring Boot configured ObjectMapper to the JacksonJsonProvider we will catch the error like this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type 'java.time.Instant' not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
```

to fix it we have to init JacksonJsonProvider with Spring configured ObjectMapper, like the code below

```
    @Autowired
    DataService dataService;
    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;
    @Autowired
    SessionService sessionService;
    @Autowired
    StatusService statusService;

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider() {
        JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
        provider.setMapper(objectMapper);
        return provider;
    }


    @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean server = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        server.setProviders(Stream.of(jsonProvider()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        server.setBus(bus);
        server.setServiceBeans(Stream
                .of(dataService, eventService, sessionService, statusService)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return server.create();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have issue with Spring Batch Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer, the solution is:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).findAndRegisterModules();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
            serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factory.setSerializer(serializer);
            return factory.getObject();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Couchbase introduced a `@Bean` factory method in class `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration`, which produces an `ObjectMapper` bean so that Spring does not create its own and correct one (automatically including the java-time module stuff).

Here is the offending source file:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blame/4.2.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration.java#L309

The bug report is here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1209

This has been fixed in Spring-Data-Couchbase 4.3