# Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default Issue :

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having a tough time understanding java.time.Instant library. I am not sure where there is not a straightforward solution way to implement Instant library. I have a spring-boot project where I have created RESTful service with CRUD operation on MongoDB. Everything was ok until I introduced Instant updatedOn & Instant createdOn in DTO.

Here sample code of my POST response where failure is occurring.

```
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> create(@RequestBody CLMDto CLMDto) {

    CLMDto createdCLMDto =
        CLMService.create(CLMDto);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        .header(
            RESPONSE_HEADER_LOCATION, CLM_URL + "/" + createdCLMDto.getId())
        .body(ResponseDto.builder().value(createdCLMDto).build()); //--------------------->**Failing here**
  }
```

My response DTO looks something like this

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class ResponseDto {

  private Integer count;
  private Object value;
  private Object error;
  private Object info;
}
```

and CLMDto

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AdminDataDto {
  
  private Instant createdOn;
  private Instant updatedOn;
  @JsonProperty(value = "updatedByName", access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
  private String updatedByName;
}
```

In debugger, i noticed place where exception is happening variable createdCLMDto has following values

```
createdOn:Instant@193 "2021-03-27T11:53:24.774765300Z"
updatedByName:test
updatedOn:Instant@195 "2021-03-27T11:53:24.774765300Z"
```

as I am using Lombok plugins so I can't debug inside and find the root cause on autogenerated code. I am not looking for a solution but a suggestion where things can go wrong here. My exact error is

```
  Type definition error: [simple type, class java.time.Instant]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module \"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310\" to enable 
handling (through reference chain: 
com.abc.service.dto.ResponseDto[\"value\"]->com.abc.dto.AdminDataDto[\"createdOn\"])",
```

Needless to say but I already tried the solution provided here to updated maven libraries but no success.
I find many questions on StackOverflow around this library but no one is explaining the easiest way to implement this libarary.

I have already following dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have already tried the solution provided here
[Java 8 date time types serialized as object with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120363/java-8-date-time-types-serialized-as-object-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Did you do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120519/438154)? Show us.

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using ?

Comment: I am using spring boot version = 2.4.3

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not sure about adding a new bean here. Are there any alternatives?  Also, I see that answer is not marked as accepted as well so I am a bit reluctant to try this. The one which is accepted, I already tried but didn't work.  thanks

Comment: I have already tried the solution provided here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120363/java-8-date-time-types-serialized-as-object-with-spring-boot but still, this question is marked as close and asking me to create a new question if that doesn't solve the problem. Strange!

Comment: You just have to register the module, just like the error message is telling you.

Comment: I have the same issue, with ZonedDateTime everything worked fine with springboot 2.4.5, stopped working with 2.5.0

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do you have the following artifact into your project ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

According to the [spring source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#L827), if the class `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule` is present in your classpath, the `JavaTimeModule` should be registered

Comment: Yes, I already have this dependency in pom.xml . I have updated the question

Comment: Thanks for pointing exact source code. I did it and now it is working
  @Bean
  ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
  return objectMapper;
  }

Comment: You shouldn't create the object mapper by yourself, normally spring boot do it for you. Do you have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in your code (this annotation declare `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which configure your application automatically depending on what you have in your classpath and properties)

Comment: Thanks.This clears my doubt.

Comment: [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper#2-jackson2objectmapperbuildercustomizer](An example of overriding the) `ObjectMapper` instead of re-creating in Spring using `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`

Comment: private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());