# Can I store a date in h2 database using long data type for date field in entity object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date

I am new to spring boot, working on a project, and recently an experienced developer just told me that when creating an entity table, that has a field that should deal with dates the best approach is to use long, something like this:

```
 private Long deliveryDate;
```

The thing is that I have never seen anything being done like this before, I do not understand how this should exactly work, and I couldn't find an answer anywhere I searched for it, so do you think that some of you can help me?

Comment: I'd question very much his "best approach". Is it a date or a datetime? Are timezones involved (in case of a datetime). Why would they not use a native datatype of the database? You can't just say "this is the best, use it" without explaining **why** it's "the best". That's poor software engineering.

Comment: @Kayaman my question was if I could use long instead of date or datetime, or localdate or anything like this

Comment: Yes, but just because you can, doesn't necessarily mean you should. A [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is essentially a long value.

Comment: @Kayaman let's say I still want to use long, how exactly should I do it?

Comment: Same way you persist any long value. You'll just have to work with a `Long` instead of an actual useful date class, converting every time you need to work with it.

Comment: @Kayaman and I do not need any annotation?

Answer (score 0):

The fellow developer is probably referring to an *instant*, a certain point on the timeline at which the *thing* (probably order) is delivered.

The commonly used notation of an instant is the Unix Timestamp. It's the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, at midnight UTC. This number does not depend on timezone.

I would use `Instant` instead of `Long`, as this is the type that represents such a, well, instant. I do not know for sure whether it is automagically wired by Spring Boot, but you *may* have to add the JSR 310 module if you encounter problems. [Here is more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120363/java-8-date-time-types-serialized-as-object-with-spring-boot/47120519).

Comment: and it will work without any other annotations, or should just use instant instead of long?