# Spring Boot: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` not supported by default

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jsr310

I have added the JavaTimeModule but still not able to get OffsetDateTime working on getting some data from RethinkDB
@Configuration
public class JacksonOffsetDateTimeMapper{

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
}
```

}

Gradle dependencies for jackson:
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.1'

implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'

implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-parameter-names', version: '2.13.1'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 date time types serialized as object with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120363/java-8-date-time-types-serialized-as-object-with-spring-boot)

Answer (score 2):

Objects which are not manage by Spring and use "new ObjectMapper()" instead of autowiring it, will still face that issue.
I was facing this issue while configuring a MappingJackson2MessageConverter to use with JMS, so in this case I had to set the ObjectMapper explicitly to the MappingJackson2MessageConverter object, as shown below.

```
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();

        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

> Additionally, we can also add the @Bean annotation on top of the
> objectMapper method, this way Spring managed objects will use this
> mapper instead.

In case there is already an ObjectMapper managed by Spring, we can just inject the ObjectMapper in the messageConvert, like below.

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) 
{
   MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new 
   MappingJackson2MessageConverter();

   converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
   converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
   converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
   return converter;
}
```